# Parsing data Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Controller:

```
@Controller
    public class WeatherController {

    @GetMapping("/weather")
    public String weatherForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("weather",new WeatherServiceImpl());
        return "weather";
    }

    @PostMapping("/weather")
    public String weatherSubmit(@ModelAttribute WeatherServiceImpl weather) {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/weather}" th:object="${weather}" method="post">
    <p>City: <input type="text" th:field="*{city}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

result template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'city: ' + ${weather.city}" />
<a href="/weather">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am trying to get city name from user using a form and parse it to object. It parses to object. But I try to show the city name that I got from /weather it wont go to /result and will show an error message 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 20 20:42:53 EEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/result.html]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change post method as this.

```
@PostMapping("/weather")
    public String weatherSubmit( WeatherServiceImpl weather,Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("weather",weather);
        return "result";
    }
```

Find working code here. https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app/commit/b322644255e044ca5959460dd7d9f7a048a5f6d3

Answer (score 0):

Please try closing paragraph tag.

```
<p th:text="'city: ' + ${weather.city}" ></p>
```

Comment: could you please check on which line error occurs exactly

Comment: It doesn't specify line, it shows the message on browser at localhost:8080